# ListView : delete button does not triggers datasource's #destroy?

Tags: kendo-ui

In the kendo-ui's listview sample [1], there is a "delete" button that removes an item from the list (at least visually). I have supposed the datasource's #destroy method will be called but it does seems to be the case [2].

Did I missed something?
Thanks in advance!

[1] http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/listview/editing
[2] http://dojo.telerik.com/@sebfz1/IPUyE

Comment: I also found this to be a caused when the data being returned has a zero Id.  Then deleting it will remove it from the list, but not fire the datasource update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the actual kendo demo you linked, the Destroy *is* called when you click the delete button.  It is only your changed example where it is not.

The reason for this is that you *cannot* mix object transport configuration with function transport configuration like you are doing....they must all be objects OR all be functions.  Your read/create/update are objects but your delete is a function.

From http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport

> All transport actions (read, update, create, destroy) must be defined in the same way, that is, as functions or as objects. Mixing the different configuration alternatives is not possible.

Comment: You are definitely right! I forgot this (weird) behavior when I did the sample. I double checked by making `read` a callback and I can see it is working here. (so my "real" problem should reside somewhere else...). Thanks you very much anyway! :)